# Where does the code for the About page for my shopify site live?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I am trying to simply edit the format (float from left to center and remove two column layout into one column) of my about page on my Shopify site.

I have edited the html of the page directly using chrome dev tools (to confirm what I am doing is going to make the page look like I want it to).

My issue is that Shopify has a specific global section in the admin where you can edit just the content of the about page. Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find anything on that page that allows me to edit the pages code directly.

And when I look at the theme code for the main site, I cannot find any .liquid files that seem to be related to the about page.

Anybody with Shopify coding experience able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: If you want to create a special content you can create a  template for that  other wise code in editor will work other wise page.liquid will work